# Is Music produced by computer's Halal?

Tags: halal-haram, music

Is Music, if made with software on a Computer Halal?

Answer (score 1):

It's not important how the music produced, the important is what produced!
if your music is in "ghena" category, you should be aware to heard it.
otherwise it'll be halal insha'allah.

Comment: What does ghena mean?

Comment: @Xitas "Ghena" or "غنا" in Arabic is a type of music which made you estrange from god and Islam! recognition of this music type or singing for everyone usually is on his/her own. but there are some general rules defined by scholars like listening to women singing or something like this. but overall, you should recognize what music is suitable for you or not.

Comment: can we call adding sound of instrument "Ghene" because we use rhythm in naat too.

Answer (score 0):

Salam
Brother Amir's answer is completely true. Just notice that there are different definitions for "Ghena" or Haram Music among Muslim scholars. You should decide according to your sect and its sharia rules.